# Identify a plant with pronounced white veins on dark green ovate leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

For Mother's day I bought my mother a basket with three different kind of flowers.
She wants to take them out of the basket and into their own pots, and needs to know what plants are they to take proper care of them.

The basket's label is *extremely helpful* stating just "Flower Basket" and nothing else.

My mother knows quite a bit of gardening but doesn't know these specific plants and asked me to help her identifying them, but my gardening knowledge is negative so I think that together we average 0 knowledge altogether.

These are the pictures of one of the plants in the basket, would it be possible to identify it?

---

[image: Plant A - Image 1]
[image: Plant A - Image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one's Fittonia verschaffeltii, common name silver nerve plant. Needs high humidity, often grown in greenhouses or terrariums to supply the moist air it needs [https://www.amazon.com/Silver-Nerve-Plant-Fittonia-Verschaffeltii/dp/B00I9E341Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I9E341Q)