# Identifying a flower basket - Plant 2

Tags: identification

In relation to this question: [Identifying a flower basket - Plant 1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38468/identifying-a-flower-basket-plant-1)

For mother's day I bought my mother a basket with three different kind of flowers. She wants to take them out of the basket and into their own pots, and needs to know what plants are they to take proper care of them.

The basket's label is extremely helpfull stating just "Flower Basket" and nothing else.

My mother knows quite a bit of gardening but doesn't know these specific plants and asked me to help her identifying them, but my gardening knowledge is negative so I think that together we average 0 knowledge alltogether.

These are the pictures of the second of the plants in the basket, would it be possible to identify it?

---

**PLANT B**

[image: Plant B - Image 1]
[image: Plant B - Image 2]

---

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, probably a variety known as 'hot pink' although varietal names vary. It's usually a houseplant, but can be grown outside if the weather is frost free https://www.thegardener.co.za/kalanchoe-blossfeldiana-2/