# Identify a plant with a woody trunk and big, long, green leaves with yellow edges

Tags: identification

Follow up to these questions:

- [Identify a plant with pronounced white veins on dark green ovate leaves](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38468/identify-a-plant-with-pronounced-white-veins-on-dark-green-ovate-leaves#38468)
- [Identifying a flower basket - Plant 2](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38470/identifying-a-flower-basket-plant-2)

For Mother's day I bought my mother a basket with three different kind of flowers. She wants to take them out of the basket and into their own pots, and needs to know what plants are they to take proper care of them.

The basket's label is *extremely helpful* stating just "Flower Basket" and nothing else.

My mother knows quite a bit of gardening but doesn't know these specific plants and asked me to help her identifying them, but my gardening knowledge is negative so I think that together we average 0 knowledge altogether.

These are the pictures of the third plant in the basket, would it be possible to identify it?

[image: General View of the plant]
[image: Close up of the Trunk]

---

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Dracaena, most likely Dracaena fragrans, though there are many varieties of Dracaena and often some confusion over the varietal names. Commonly called corn plant, sometimes known as Cane plant, because they form these woody canes like trunks https://www.thespruce.com/grow-dracaena-fragrans-indoors-1902748